# How to replace "let/in" construction with "where" in IO () function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am studying Haskell and trying my first IO functions. Here a simple program that calculates the area of a rectangle, it works fine:

```
squareCalc :: IO ()
squareCalc = do
  putStrLn "Pease enter the lenght"
  length <- getLine
  putStrLn "Pleas enter the width"
  width <- getLine
  let square = read length * read width
   in putStrLn ("The square is " ++ show square)
```

However, when I try to replace "let/in" with "where":

```
squareCalc2 :: IO ()
squareCalc2 = do
  putStrLn "Pease enter the lenght"
  length <- getLine
  putStrLn "Pleas enter the width"
  width <- getLine
  putStrLn ("The square is " ++ show square) 
    where
       square = (read length) * (read width)
```

the compiler returns an error error:

> Variable not in scope: width :: String

I am wondering if there ever possible to use "where" in functions like this?

Comment: By the way, `readLn` is generally better than `getLine`+`read`. It manifests parsing errors sooner, and as `IO` exceptions rather than pure ones. (Of course, even better still is real error-handling...)

Comment: Note that in `do` blocks we can write `let x = ...` without an `in`, and without indenting further the rest of the code. This lets you define `x` next to its use, while `where` could be used, at best, only at the very end.

Comment: `let`/`in` is the most general way to introduce auxiliary definitions. `where` is a special case for attaching auxiliary definitions to a binding equation, scoped over the whole of the right hand side. Anything you can do with `where` you can do with `let`/`in`, but not the other way around.

Comment: @Ben How do I write `f x y | even x = z + x | even y = z + y | otherwise = z where z = x + y` with `let`/`in`?

Comment: @amalloy `f x y = let { z = x + y; r | even x = z + x | even y = z + y | otherwise = z } in r`  :P . You're right though, I guess I was overselling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you indented

```
putStrLn ("The square is " ++ show square) 
  where
     square = (read length) * (read width)
```

makes me think that you want this code to be treated as an expression. The problem is that `where` isn't legal in expressions. It's only legal after the right hand side of a variable/function/pattern binding.

You might expect to just get a syntax error then, but that isn't how the layout rule works. When the parser encounters a syntax error, and there is an open implicitly-curly-bracketed block from the layout rule, it will close that block to try to make the error disappear. In this case, it works: your code becomes

```
squareCalc2 = do
  { ... }
    where
       square = (read length) * (read width)
```

which is syntactically valid. But `length` and `width` are only in scope inside the curly brackets, so compilation fails anyway.

Note that `let` without `in` is allowed in `do` blocks as a convenience, so you can write this:

```
squareCalc = do
  ...
  let square = read length * read width
  putStrLn ("The square is " ++ show square)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's not possible. Annoying. The closest you can get is to make the thing in the `where` block be a function.

```
squareCalc2 = do
    ...
    putStrLn ("The square is " ++ show (square length width))
    where square length width = read length * read width
```

Comment: I think this answer would be better if you explained *why* instead of just remarking that it's annoying. i.e., that `let`/`in` is an ordinary expression, while `where` is syntax that attaches to a pattern match.